# Perfect power nim

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics, number-theory

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Ann and Ben has $m$ stones, and each of them takes exactly the perfect power of $n$ stones ($n^k$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer) in order, starting from Ann. Who takes the last stone wins. When will Ann have a winning strategy, and when does Ben has a winning strategy?

---

Problem by myself. Remember to pay attention to the tags!

---

Hint 1:

> Try small cases of $n$.

Comment: You may wish to assert that k is greater than 1...

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem I don't see why. $n^0=1$ seems like a perfectly valid move to play. If $k$ had to be non-zero then all moves would be multiples of $n$ stones, and $m$ would also have to be a multiple of $n$ to even be able to finish the game, and then you might as well group clusters of $n$ stones together and treat them as individual stones in a game where $k=0$ is allowed.

Comment: Ah, I failed to realize that n was a *fixed* number - no wonder I couldn't find a pattern!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For odd values of $n$:

> Every move takes an odd number. Therefore the parity of the number of stones remaining alternates between odd and even. Ann wins if $m$ is odd, Ben wins if $m$ is even, regardless of what moves they choose to make.

For $n=2$:

> If $m$ is not a multiple of $3$ then Ann wins by taking either $1$ or $2$ to make it a multiple of $3$. If $m$ is a multiple of $3$ then any move that Ann makes will turn it into a number that is not a multiple of $3$ (which cannot be $0$ so definitely not taking the last stone), allowing Ben to win with the same strategy.
>  So with perfect play the number of stones remaining alternates between multiples and non-multiples of $3$, and the one who keeps leaving multiples of $3$ must win.

For $n=4$:

> It is safe to leave numbers that at $0$ or $2$ modulo $5$. If the starting value $m$ is already such a number then Ann loses, if not she can take $1$ or $4$ to make it such a number and win.

This generalises to all even $n$.

> If the number of stones remaining modulo $n+1$ is $0$, $2$, $4$, ..., $n-2$, then the next player to move loses. If not, the next player can win by taking either $1$ or $n$ to leave such a number for the other player (though other winning moves may be available too).

Proof:

> Numbers that are $0$, $2$, $4$, ..., or $n-2$ modulo $n+1$ we'll call winning numbers. All other numbers are losing numbers. We need to prove that:
>  1) any move applied to a winning number produces a losing number,
>  and that
>  2) for any losing number there is a move that produces a winning number.
>
>  Part 1 follows from the fact that modulo $n+1$ we have $$n^k\equiv (n+1-1)^k\equiv  (-1)^k\equiv \pm1$$
>  So every move increments or decrements the residue modulo $n+1$. The winning numbers are non-adjacent, so every move applied to a winning number produces a losing number.
>
>  For part 2, we can simply produce the winning move explicitly for each losing number. If the losing number is $1$, $3$, ..., $n-1$ modulo $n+1$ then take $1$ stone. If the losing number is $n$ modulo $n+1$ then take $n$ stones. In all cases you produce a winning number.
>
>  So the player who first produces a winning number will be able to continue to do so in all subsequent moves, and the game alternates between winning and losing numbers until that player wins.

Comment: Good! This solution is more detailed.

Answer (score 5):

If n = 2k + 1 is odd then

> Ann wins if and only if m is odd. Correct strategy is making any legal move (or indeed allowing opponent to call your moves).

If n = 2k is even then

> Ann wins if and only if m = 1,3, ..., 2k-1 modulo 2k+1 or m = 2k modulo 2k+1. One winning strategy (but not the fastest) is taking 1 or n stones to ensure the next value of m = 0,2,...,2k-2 modulo 2k+1. For instance if n=4 then Ann should make sure the number of stones left for Ben is 5s or 5s + 2 for some integer s

Comment: I took a long time completing my answer, and you pipped me to the post. Well done! +1

Answer (score -2):

Let's assume $n, k>1$. Let's call the last turn $M_x$ and $M_x\leq n^k$. If the number of turns is even then the first player loses; if the number of turns is odd the first player wins.